# Getting error 'Error: spawn git ENOENT' while deploying React JS application to Github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, deployment, github-pages

While doing deployment of my React JS application to Github.io, I'm getting below error.

I followed below steps to deploy my React application.

> Added in package.json file, "homepage": "https://[username].github.io/[appname]",

Added in scripts:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
```

> Ran **npm run deploy**

It gives below error. Error log attached below.

````
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: my-app@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\React Projects\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111/bin;E:\Development\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin;E:\Development\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.2.3/bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\Maddy\AppData\Roaming\npm
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: E:\React Projects\my-app
9 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: my-app@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\React Projects\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111/bin;E:\Development\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin;E:\Development\Apache Maven\apache-maven-3.2.3/bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\Maddy\AppData\Roaming\npm
14 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: E:\React Projects\my-app
15 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -b master -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
19 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd E:\React Projects\my-app
21 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v10.16.0
24 verbose npm  v6.9.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
````

Comment: Did you run ```npm install gh-pages --save-dev``` to install the gh-pages module?

Comment: Hi Adam, Yes, I ran this command before running 'npm run deploy' but I got this error.

Comment: Using the ```-b master``` option might be a mistake. Pushing to the results to the master branch might not be accepted by github

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but I tried with `gh-pages -d build` as well and still getting same error.

Comment: Maybe try running ```NODE_DEBUG=gh-pages npm run deploy``` to get some more debug info. The current error you provided doesn't say much at all :(

Comment: I see NODE_DEBUG is depreciated and could not use this. I'm still looking for the fix. :(

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have the same error :?

Comment: Hi @Matheew , yeah I could fix this issue by following these steps:

Make sure you enter correct UserID/Password while entering the credentials in the GitHub GUI screen.

Try upgrading your Git version to the latest one. You can do the same by downloading the latest Git from https://git-scm.com/downloads

Select GitHub Pages source to master branch

You can refer this link for more info: https://medium.com/@maddydeepak/how-to-deploy-react-js-application-on-github-pages-5db05152e5aa